# Sqoop import converting TINYINT to BOOLEAN

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I am attempting to import a MySQL table of NFL play results into HDFS using Sqoop.  I issued the following command to achieve this:

```
sqoop import \
--connect jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/nfl \
--username <username> -P \
--table play
```

Unfortunately, there are columns of type `TINYINT`, which are being converted to booleans upon import.  For instance, there is a 'quarter' column for which quarter of the game the play occurred in.  The value in this column is converted to 'true' if the play occurred in the first quarter and 'false' otherwise.

In fact, I did a `sqoop import-all-tables`, importing the entire NFL database I have, and it behaves like this uniformly.

Is there a way around this, or perhaps some argument for `import` or `import-all-tables` that prevents this from happening?

Comment: The mapping for each table column has to be handled separately using map-column-hive

Comment: This is happening irrespective of my use of Hive.  The files in my HDFS home directory (e.g., after running the above Sqoop job) exhibit this phenomenon as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `tinyInt1isBit=false` in your JDBC connection URL. Something like

`jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/nfl?tinyInt1isBit=false`

Another solution would be to explicitly override the column mapping for the datatype TINYINT(1) column. For example, if the column name is `foo`, then pass the following option to Sqoop during import: `--map-column-hive foo=tinyint`. In the case of non-Hive imports to HDFS, use `--map-column-java foo=integer`.

[Source](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_mysql_import_of_tinyint_1_from_mysql_behaves_strangely)